# Tangent Spaces and Tangent Vectors

Tags: differential-geometry

The Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) gives one of the definitions of the tangent space at $x\in M$ as the set of all derivations at $x$. I'm guessing a tangent vector is just an element of the tangent space. This definition seems more abstract compared to the intuitive notion of a tangent vector at $x$ being the derivative of a curve in $M$ passing through $x$. To help elucidate the first definition, could I get some examples (including calculations) of elements in the tangent space of $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\in\mathbb{S}^2$ where $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the unit sphere? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are something like five equivalent notions of "a tangent vector" at a point $P$ of a  manifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^n$:

1. the derivative of a curve passing through $P$ and lying on $M$
2. A derivation at $P$
3. A "collection of coordinates that transforms according to the rule ...."
4. An expression $a_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \ldots + a_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$ which, when considered as a differential operator on functions on $\mathbb R^n$, is zero (at $P$) on every function $f : \mathbb R^n \to R$ that's locally constant at $P$.

   ... others I cannot remember.

Michael Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* has a nice chapter showing that all of these are the same thing...but it *is* a whole chapter of a book.

To answer your question (very slightly), for a smooth function $f$ on the 2-sphere, there's some smooth function $g$ defined on a neighborhood of the 2-sphere in 3-space that agrees with $f$ on the sphere itself (to show this probably requires the inverse function theorem or something); such a $g$ is called an *extension* of f.

Now I'll define for you a derivation
$$
f \mapsto H(f)
$$
by saying that $H(f)$ is the restriction of $K(g)$ to the 2-sphere, where
$$
K(g) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}.
$$
Now you might ask "How do you know you get the same result no matter *which* smooth extension $g$ you pick?" Clearly $K(g)$ will be different for different $g$s. But for all of these, the restriction of $K(g)$ to the 2-sphere will be the same. Why? Well, because thinking of 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - \frac{\partial }{\partial y}.
$$
as a vector (where the "partials" are the basis!), you have
$$
[1, -1, 0]
$$
which is orthogonal to the gradient $[2x, 2y, 2z]$ of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$, which is the function whose zero-set is the sphere, at the point you chose. Critical to the proof of "independence of the choice of $g$" is something involving the chain rule, $f$, and $g$ which I cannot reconstruct in my head right this moment. :(

Now that's skipping a lot of steps...approximately one whole Spivak-chapter worth. But at least it's a concrete example for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I have misunderstood something but couldn't I choose $g_1\left(x,y,z\right)=x+y+z$ and $g_2\left(x,y,z\right)=x+y^4+z$ in which case $K_{\left(1/2,1/2,1/\sqrt{2}\right)}\left(g_1\right)=0$ but $K_{\left(1/2,1/2,1/\sqrt{2}\right)}\left(g_2\right)=-1$. Also, I can see how $\left(1,-1,0\right)$ is a tangent vector to my chosen point in the intuitive sense but with the definition I'm using, shouldn't a tangent vector be a derivation?

Comment: 2. The function $f \mapsto H(f)$ is a derivation. (You have to prove this, of course, but it follows from the multiplication rule for derivatives).  1. You can choose those two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$, but when restricted to $S^2$, they are not equal. So they are not both extensions of the same function $f$. (In particular, their difference is $y^4 - y$, which is not everywhere zero on $S^2$.

Comment: So $g$ has to be chosen so that its restriction to the sphere must be $f$. Finally just to confirm, (1,-1,0) is an element of the tangent space but another way of writing it is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Does this mean that if I have a more general form for the derivation at $x$, say $D_x=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ then $\left(v_1,\cdots,v_n\right)$ would be the tangent vector (with respect to the basis $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\}$)?

Comment: I just realized that when I introduced $g$, I left out something that I said 2 paragraphs later: that $g$ must be an extension of $f$. I'll edit to fix. To answer your second question: yes. And for $D_x$ to be a derivation at $x$, it'll turn out that the vector $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ needs to actually be *tangent* (in the intuitive sense).

Comment: That makes things clear for me now. I should mention to anyone else who may stumble upon this that the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in my previous comment should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.